# MySQL 5.6 - Query Performance Issue. Searching for Slug

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I've a case where I don't know how to better the performance of this query.

This is a simple query to the [Geonames.org](https://www.geonames.org/) database.

The query:

```
SELECT name, latitude, longitude FROM geoname 
WHERE 
slugify(geoname.name) = 'lisboa' 
and geoname.country = 'PT' 
and geoname.fclass in ('A', 'T')
```

The Explain:

```
id, select_type,   table,   type,     possible_keys,     key, key_len,    ref,    rows, Extra
 1,      SIMPLE, geoname,    ref,    fclass,country, country,      11,  const,   73462, Using index condition; Using where
```

I know that the problem is this **where clause**:

```
slugify(geoname.name) = 'lisboa'
```

I cannot index this. The **slugify()** is a MySQL function that slugify the geoname, for example **New York** becomes **new-york**.

What options shoul I consider to have a better performance in this situation. What can I do?

Comment: *I cannot index this.* And you can do nothing with it in your server version - 5.6 do not know about calculated fields. The only way I see is to add one more field into table structure with the value of `slugify(name)` filled using trigger logic and not altered directly. You may use this field value and index the table by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to MySQL-5.7 and then MySQL-8.0 (for safety, 1 major version at a time).

Then use [Secondary indexes on virtual colums as such](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html):

```
ALTER TABLE geoname
ADD slug VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (slugify(name)),
ADD INDEX slug_country_fclass (slug, country, fclass);
```

If you wish to stay on 5.6, and you don't change geoname value often, you can denormalise as:

```
ALTER TABLE geoname
ADD slug VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
ADD INDEX slug_country_fclass (slug, country, fclass);
```

Populate the column with:

```
UPDATE geoname SET slug=slugify(name);
```

After doing one of the above steps, change the query to use the slug generated column as:

```
SELECT name, latitude, longitude FROM geoname 
WHERE 
slug = 'lisboa' 
and geoname.country = 'PT' 
and geoname.fclass in ('A', 'T')
```

The new index can then be used for all the criteria of your query.

Comment: And if you are working with an older version, it is probably worth it to add `slug` as a new column.